# Image link in Firefox not covering the whole image

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just noticed a weird bug with Firefox (it works fine with IE and Chrome, all 3 of them at latest version). The brand image is not clickable when the screen is large and the navbar is fully expanded (I can see a few pixels to the left where the click appears, but clicking the image does nothing). But if you resize your screen to have a small width, the navbar collapses and then the link is clickable.

I'm using Bootstrap v3.0.0 for the navbar.

Any ideas? An issue with the padding, or fixed positioning? I couldn't find anything closely similar on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird issue.

Overriding the bootstrap3 rule of `.navbar-header { float: left; }` seems to do the trick:

```
.navbar-header {
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: It does work, thanks! Although I still don't understand why the float would break things.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really understand it myself. Seems to be a bug, or something like that.